# How to force RequestMapping redirect to respect the calling URL's protocol. (HTTPS/HTTP)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java-8, apache-camel, swagger

#### Scenario:

I have a redirect for the swagger-ui pages to make it easier to get to. (camel makes me sad)
When I'm running locally, I am using HTTP.
When I'm running in the test servers, I am using HTTPS.
Alternatively, I'd be good with configuring the camel flows (xml) to change the default url for the swagger pages.

#### Expected - (https redirected to https) and (http redirected to http):

`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui` --> `http://localhost:8080/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/api/swagger&validatorUrl=`
`https://remote.com/swagger-ui` --> `https://remote.com/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/api/swagger&validatorUrl=`

#### Actual - https & http redirected to http:

`http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui` --> `http://localhost:8080/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/api/swagger&validatorUrl=`
`https://remote.com/swagger-ui` --> `http://remote.com/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/api/swagger&validatorUrl=`

#### Code:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class SwaggerController {

    @RequestMapping("/swagger-ui")
    public String redirectToUi() {
        return "redirect:/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/api/swagger&validatorUrl=";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/swagger-ui.html")
    public String redirectToUi2() {
        return "redirect:/webjars/swagger-ui/index.html?url=/api/swagger&validatorUrl=";
    }
}
```

```
        <restConfiguration
                component="servlet"
                apiContextPath="swagger"
                contextPath="api"
                enableCORS="true"
                bindingMode="json">
            <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>

            <!-- setup swagger api description -->
            <apiProperty key="base.path" value="api"/>
            <apiProperty key="api.version" value=".0.0.1"/>
            <apiProperty key="api.title" value="Some Forms"/>
            <apiProperty key="api.description" value="Description Here"/>
            <apiProperty key="api.contact.name" value="Contact here"/>
        </restConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because a logical view name (such as "redirect:/myapp/some/resource") will redirect your call to the current Servlet context, in your case the scheme of your context is HTTP.

You need to implement different contexts for this case (one for HTTP and one for HTTPS) and then you can proxy the call with camel-servlet

Context 1 - http:

```
from("servlet:myapp?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("http://newURL?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
```

Context 2 - https:

```
from("servlet:myapp?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
.to("https://newURL?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
```

Comment: Shouldn't the context be HTTPS, since the URL is HTTPS? I'm not trying to redirect from an HTTP to HTTPS, I'm getting redirected (unexpectedly) from HTTPS to HTTP by default. Note, also, that I am not always going to an HTTPS URL. The redirectee needs match the redirector's protocol.

Comment: PS - This is a relative redirect, rather than an external redirect. (Though I can turn it into absolute URL if *absolutely* needed.)